# how to get checkbox in each cell of column heading ,in yii2 gridview?

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am new to yii2 and using yii2 gridview in my project.. Is it possible to have checkbox in each column near column heading ?? 
here is code

```
<?php 

    $gridColumns = [
                     ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                     ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],  

                    'name', //checkbox then 'name'
                    'company_mail', //checkbox then 'company_mail' for each column
                    'no_employees',
                    'email:email', 
                    .
                    .
                    .];
            echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
    ]); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution.

```
<?php 

    $gridColumns = [
                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
                        [
                            'header' => '<input type="checkbox"> Name',
                            'attribute' => 'name',
                        ],
                        [
                            'header' => '<input type="checkbox"> Company Email',
                            'attribute' => 'company_mail',
                        ],  
                        'no_employees',
                        'email:email', 


                   ];

    echo GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                'columns' => $gridColumns,
            ]); 
?>
```

If you want checkbox on all the rows of column then your code should be

```
<?php 

    $gridColumns = [
                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
                        [
                            'header' => '<input type="checkbox"> Name',
                            'attribute' => 'name',
                        ],
                        [
                            'header' => '<input type="checkbox"> Company Email',
                            'attribute' => 'company_mail',
                            'value' => function ($model) {                      
                                    return '<input type="checkbox" name="YOURCHECKBOXNAME"> '.$model->company_mail;
                            },
                        ], // this will generate checkbox at header as well as each rows of this column
                        'no_employees',
                        'email:email', 


                   ];

    echo GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                'columns' => $gridColumns,
            ]); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is creating your own dataColumn class and setting the default value for the header with a checkbox.

```
<?php 
class myDataColumn extends yii\grid\DataColumn {

    public $header = "somehtml";

}
?>
```

Then in your gridview set property `dataColumnClass` with the name of your custom dataColumn. Take care that only those attributes without a `class` property defined will use your class. (ActionColumn, as an example, will not show your custom header)

If you need more than a simple fixed html you can override method `renderHeaderCellContent` to even concatenate with the label of the column.

See [Yii2 Guide: DataColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html)